# How to disable duplicated items in random.choice

Tags: python, list, random

I want to grab a random items in a list using `random.choices()`, but I don't need to grab some multiple items.
Example:

```py
import random
mylist = ['python', 'c++', 'html', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']
print(random.choices(mylist, k=4)
```

in sometimes it returns this output:

```py
['python', 'html', 'JavaScript', 'JavaScript']
```

So I want to remove the duplicated JavaScript, so it remains only one JavaScript and replace the duplicated one with a new item

```py
['python', 'html', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']
```

Comment: Try `random.sample()` or `random.shuffle()` and take the first four.

Comment: Ali: Please search for similar existing questions before asking new ones here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this :

```
from random import sample
mylist = ['python', 'c++', 'html', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']
print(sample(mylist, k=4))
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer, though it lacks details. The difference between `random.sample` and `random.choice` is that `sample` is guaranteed to sample _unique_ elements which `choice` samples with replacement.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Set list for this implementation.
A Set list allows you to store any type of info, but it doesn't allow you to have duplicate values.

See how Set works [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp).

If you want a determined number of samples, then you should make a loop
where list size must reach to the number of samples wanted.

```
import Random

myset ={}
nSamples = 3
a =['pear','orange','cherry','pineapple','banana']
while(len(myset) != 3){
myset.add(Random.choices(a,k=1))
}
```

Comment: If you convert the choices to a set, you're not guaranteed to get as many samples as you want.

Comment: If you want a determined number of samples you can actually do a loop where list size must reach to the number of samples.

Comment: Or you can use `random.sample`. :-)

Comment: Not questioning the best solution, but giving another way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can convert that list to a set so no doubles will happen. Even if you give doubles in the list, the set will only have singles

```
import random
mylist = ['python', 'c++', 'html', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']
my_set = set(random.choices(mylist, k=4))
print(my_set)
```

you can later convert the set to a list again.

Comment: If you convert the choices to a set, you're not guaranteed to get as many samples as you want.